# DB2 Data Server Client 11.1 package not providing all tools

Tags: windows, db2, db2-luw

My current task at my job is to install the DB2 11.1 Data Server Client for our users on windows 10.  I grabbed the installer from IBM's site and installed it successfully, BUT it's only installing command line tools.  When looking at the 9.7 package on a windows 7 workstation, it provides a bunch of GUI based tools.  Can someone tell me where i'm going wrong?  Has anyone had success installing 11.1 on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Db2-v11 clients for Linux/Unix/Windows no longer come with the old GUI tool known as the Control-Center.

Some Db2-client types still include the Replication-Center GUI. You need to choose your [Db2-client](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/c0022612.html) type carefully.

The replacement for the Control Center is IBM Data Studio, which is a separate download, and also for some functionality the IBM Data Server Manager.

[Data Studio 4.x download link](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037681)

[IBM Data Server Manager download link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/dsm/index.html)

Other companies supply alternative lightweight GUI client tools that work with Db2. For example Db-visualizer, Squirrel-SQL and many other Java based tools. Oracle SQL-Developer also works with Db2, as does Toad for Db2.

None of those tools third-party can cope with all the different variants of Db2-functionality, especially in the area of DPF or Purescale or latest variants of syntax for different platforms. Latest versions of IBM Data Studio try to cover most cases.  But many of the third party tools are good enough for many simple use cases.